# Bootstrap - проблема с шаблоном Cover

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Столкнулся со странной проблемой, работая с Bootstrap.

Имеется простая страница, состоящая из двух частей:
1. Доработанный стандартный шаблон `Cover` (http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/)
2. Ниже `section` и в ней стдартные row, col и т.д.

Между верхней частью (`Cover`) и секцией ниже есть отступ. По идее - просвечиает `body`, правда фоновый цвет не белый а серый.

**Проблема в том что я не могу изменить этот фоновый цвет body.**
CSS для `body` судя по всему вдияет только на невидимый мне фон позади Cover.
Проверял через консоль: странно - `body` охватывает всю страницу (и cover и section), но при наведении на body в консоли, на странице выделяется только область `Cover`, без `section` и пространства между ними. Если же навести в консоли на `section`  - `section` на странице выделяетя правильно.

В чем тут может быть дело?
Заранее больше спасибо!

**UPD**

**Кажется понял в чем причина:** `CSS` шиблона `Cover` задает `html` и `body` `height="100%", в результате чего их высота становится равна размеру окна браузера. Не совсем понимаю, почему в таком случае, фоновый цвет`body` изменяется на протяжении всего документа?..

Но **главный вопрос** - как можно заменить `body` другим элементом? Так как страница продолжается ниже, `body` не должно ограничиваться областью `Cover`. Пробовал заключить `Cover` в `div` и задать ему те же `CSS` что были заданы `body`, но это не работает.

**Вот код (корректней отображается на jsfiddle):**
https://jsfiddle.net/x3ju0d9w/

```css
/*
 * Globals
 */

/* Links */

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
/* Custom default button */

.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}
/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #333;
}
body {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
/* Extra markup and styles for table-esque vertical and horizontal centering */

.site-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* For at least Firefox */
  min-height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.site-wrapper-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.cover-container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
/* Padding for spacing */

.inner {
  padding: 2rem;
}
/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}
.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}
/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}
.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
/*
 * Footer
 */

.mastfoot {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}
/*
 * Affix and center
 */

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  /* Pull out the header and footer */
  .masthead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mastfoot {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
  }
  /* Start the vertical centering */
  .site-wrapper-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  /* Handle the widths */
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 100%;
    /* Must be percentage or pixels for horizontal alignment */
  }
}
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .masthead,
  .mastfoot,
  .cover-container {
    width: 42rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<div class="site-wrapper">

  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">

    <div class="cover-container">

      <div class="masthead clearfix">
        <div class="inner">
          <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
          <nav class="nav nav-masthead">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="inner cover">
        <h1 class="cover-heading">Cover your page.</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cover is a one-page template for building simple and beautiful home pages. Download, edit the text, and add your own fullscreen background photo to make it your own.</p>
        <p class="lead">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">Learn more</a>
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="mastfoot">
        <div class="inner">
          <p>Cover template for <a href="https://getbootstrap.com">Bootstrap</a>, by <a href="https://twitter.com/mdo">@mdo</a>.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
</section>
<section class="sectionSecond">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h1>Column-left</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Column-middle</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <h1>Column-right</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Заранее еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Простите, но ничего не понятно.

Comment: Суть проблемы понятна, но без просмотра  css-файла из которого грузятся стили решить её почти нереально, разве что только методом тыка перебирать варианты из-за чего это может быть. Например, из-за того что у `body` свойство `opacity` меньше 1

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Извините, старался описать понятнее. Добавил пример с кодом и новый главный вопрос.

Comment: @MasterAlex Добавил пример, на 'jsfiddle' почему-то отображается корректнее чем здесь. Причина оказалась в 'CSS' шаблона,он задает  'html' и 'body' высоту '100%' и они остаются размером с окошко браузера в момент открытия страницы. Теперь пытаюсь понять, как можно вместо 'body' использовать для этого любой другой элемнт?..

Comment: @Rumata вам надо чтобы `body` было гарантированно больше высоты экрана?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Я хотел чтобы body по высоте сответствовало высоте страницы. Мне кажется странно когда высота дочерних элементов (контента страницы) больше высоты родитльских (body)...

Comment: @Rumata так уберите `html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}`.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Тогда Cover больше не будет занимать размер окна брузера. А нужно чтобы занимал как сейчас.

Comment: @Rumata Вам подходит мой ответ?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Да, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы `body` занимал высоту контента уберите `html, body { height: 100%; }`.

Для того, чтобы `.cover` занимал высоту экрана присвойте ему `.cover { height: 100vh }`.
 `vh` (viewport height) — единицы измерения, означающие высоту экрана в процентах.